# Separate colors for viewcontroller background and statusbar background

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I want a blue color for my navigation bar and status bar backgrounds while a white color background for the rest of the view controller. I want this for all my view controllers in the app. Naturally, I have in my BaseViewContrller for statusbar:

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
```

But this causes the whole view controller to go blue. Is adding a white UIView and constraining it to safe areas the only option or there is an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: You can change status bar color in navigation controller

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, because you're setting ViewController's `view` background color and not `navigationBar` background color. Instead set background color of navigation bar

```
navigationController?.navigationBar.backgroundColor = .blue
```

Comment: To set statusBar background, we have to change the Viewcontroller's view background.

Comment: @Kashif why? Navigation bar goes to the top of the screen.

Comment: I would add that navigationControler?.navigationBar.barTintColor = .blue might also be needed.